# increase in diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am looking at the following figure, showing the deformation of a triangular element from time $t$ to time $t+dt$. Note that the $t$ on the left leg of the isosceles triangle simply denotes our triangle at time $t$ and the $t+dt$ on the deformed triangle means at a later time $t+dt$.

[image: triangle]

According to the [notes](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-25-advanced-fluid-mechanics-fall-2005/study-materials/06_viscous_flow.pdf&ei=W_W9Uqr4EsKY4wThyoBg&usg=AFQjCNGj6pKmX04DYEHf7e4q7HiCFfhBcg&sig2=K_GBxIh5Q2Zq_X-0E3lZhg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) I am reading (page 16, eq. 28) the increase in the diagonal AC is given by

$$
\delta(AC) = \frac{a+d}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{b+c}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

It is not clear to me why that is the case. I would just have said it should be
$$
\sqrt{(a+d)^2 + (b+c)^2}
$$
but this seems not to be the case. Does anyone see how one arrives at the first expression?

Comment: I don't understand that picture (oh, these physicists!): $\;t\;$ is denoted as the left side (leg? Is that a straight triangle?), yet $\;t+dt\;$ then appears as the upper side of that new, moved-to-the-right triangle...what's going on here?

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, I will elaborate in the OP

Comment: Good idea, @BillyJean, though the same thing appears in the link you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your value for $\delta AC$ assumes that the new corner $C$ lies along the same line as the old corner $C$.  This is only the case if $(a+d)/(b+c)$ matches the slope of the old line $AC$.

As for where they got the other equation, I'm not sure.  I suspect that there is some simplification involving Taylor series at work.